# CannotResolveClassException while reading an XML file in a method

Tags: java, deserialization, xstream

I'm trying to write a class that would enable me to just write .save(); to make a permanent copies of child classes. I've created a method that creates the xml:

```
public boolean save() throws IOException{
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new KXml2Driver());

    FileWriter extenceWriter = new FileWriter(saveFile);
    xstream.alias(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), this.getClass());
    xstream.toXML(this, extenceWriter);

    return saveFile.exists();
}
```

and another one that should read it:

```
public Object loadFile(String path) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File file = new File(appRootDIR + File.separator + path);

    XStream xstream = new XStream(new KXml2Driver());
    FileReader extenceReader = new FileReader(file);

    return xstream.fromXML(extenceReader);
}
```

The problem is that i get a com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException when i try to use loadFile(). 
I've checked google and the closest hit was that different instances of xstream can't communicate. 
This could be solved by moving xstream to a class field, but then I get some errors regarding to the matter that xstream can't serialise itself.

Is there a good way to implement both read and write methods in a class without having to create a xstream instance outside of the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using an alias in `save()`, the simple class name rather than the fully qualified class name is written to the XML. This makes `loadFile()` unable to figure out what class it is referring to.

You can fix this in one of two ways:

1. Don't using aliasing - simple, but the XML won't be as clean-looking.
2. Make a method that registers *all* the aliases you want to use on an `XStream` instance, and call that method from both `save()` and `loadFile()` so that they can operate with the same set of aliases.

Comment: Thank You for your help!
Option one works great. 
Didn't figure out how to register the aliases yet but I'll try it.